# Possible to expand Bash variable in curly braces?

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

In BASH, is it possible to expand a variable in a brace expansion?

For instance, if one would like to obtain a printed sequence 1 to 10, they could
do:

```
echo {1..10}
```

let's say that instead of 10, I have a variable `rangeEnd` and would like to use that instead. Something along the lines of:

```
rangeEnd=10
echo {1..$rangeEnd}
```

This however produces `{1..10}` as opposed to `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`. Is there any way to obtain the correct sequence (`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`) using curly brace expansion?
(I'm already aware that I can use `echo $(seq 0 $(rangeEnd))`, but I'd like to see if it is indeed possible to use curly brace expansion)

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `eval` like this:

```
eval "echo {1..${rangeEnd}}"
```

Comment: Please don't encourage `eval` usage. We actually had a major security vulnerability come out in Red Hat's DHCP service today for just that reason. There are much safer ways to iterate over a numeric range. See also [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048), *eval command and security issues*. If `rangeEnd` weren't a number and instead were a value chosen by an attacker, this could result in code execution, whereas better-chosen approaches would just make that an error.

Comment: The question clearly says he knows how the approach mentioned in your answer is known to him, and want to know how the curly brace can be expanded with a variable.

Comment: I guess technically, all the solutions worked, so you all answered my question (thank you!). That being said though, is there a non-eval way that anyone is aware of?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see your point.  This risk is a non-issue if the variable is hard-coded within the script.  If the value comes from some external source, then we could safely call `eval` _only_ if we first check that the value of `${rangeEnd}` is numeric, non-negative, and that it is reasonably small.  Of course this would only be safe for this particular use case.  Other use cases would need to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis, which is presumably why you would rather say that `eval` is off limits altogether to err on the safe side.

Comment: @derek Are you trying to find a solution that uses curly brace expansion and also does not use `eval`?  If so, I don't know of such a solution.  But if you're willing to drop one of those requirements, then yes, there are multiple solutions, as you already know.

Comment: BTW, the OP does mention `seq`, but `seq` is itself bad form -- it's not built into bash, and not POSIX-standardized (and thus not available to be available on all platforms, or to have any particular behavior when it *is* installed).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
rangeEnd=10
eval echo {1..$rangeEnd}
```